# fullCalendar dayRender for agendaWeek and agendaDay

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to change the background color of cell of day. I managed to change the background color in **month view**. However when I am switching to **agendaWeek** and **agendaDay** *dayRender callback* is not getting called.

Is there any workaround in version 2?
I am using FullCalendar v2.3.1

Thanks!

Comment: I can't [reproduce your issue](http://jsfiddle.net/e3umLduc/)

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time. It seems that if you put **allDaySlot** to **false** dayRender will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

I had to override the default fullcalendar css with the following:

```
.fc-day.fc-today {
  background-color: blueviolet !important;
}
```

By using this, the *dayRender* callback is not required.